# How to I get the index of each child when looping through the root using xml Element etree?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, xml.etree

Here is my code:

```
X_train = pd.read_csv('data/train_features.txt',header=0,names=['area','length','index','complexity','lines','curves','intensity'])
y_train = pd.read_csv('labels/train_labels.txt',header=0,names=['r','g','b'])

l_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
l_model.fit(X_train,y_train)

X_test = pd.read_csv('data/test_features.txt',header=0,names=['area','length','index','complexity','lines','curves','intensity'])

with open('test.svg','rwb') as o:
    tree = ET.parse(o)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for index,child in enumerate(root):
        features = np.array(X_test.loc[index,:])
        child.set('fill',l_model.predict(features))
    tree.write('best_guess.svg')
```

As you can see I am trying to loop through each child in the root element of my svg file, and eventually set the fill element with one predicted my my linear model.

Before any of that happens however, I am stuck getting this error, I believe because my for loop isn't getting the index correctly - in other words, I don't think you can do the enumerate trick with a root element of and svg like you can with a python array. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guess.py", line 26, in <module>
    features = np.array(X_test.loc[index,:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1225, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 738, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 863, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1371, in _getitem_axis
    self._has_valid_type(key, axis)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1333, in _has_valid_type
    error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1320, in error
    (key, self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [2809] is not in the [index]'
```

it seems to not like me calling index. So yeah, how can I loop through the root while also getting the index?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with getting the `index` with `enumerate` (which works perfectly fine with root element). The error comes from `pandas`. You are expecting the dataframe will have an `index` that corresponds to the index of the child in the xml file, which it obviously doesn't.

Comment: how is it obvious? at each child in the xml file. I want to take that row. So for the first child path, I want to use the first row of the data frame. for the 2nd child path, I want to use the second row of the pandas data frame. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: Do you have any comment nodes in your xml? If yes, iterating over root does not skip comment nodes and as result index may be out of range. Try to replace this part  `for index,child in enumerate(root):` with `for index,child in enumerate(root.xpath('./*')):`